# ArcGIS Custom Toolbox crashes ArcMap 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, java

I have prepared Custom ArcToolBox using ArcObjects in java. It was working fine before though was giving NullPointerException but this something java related error and that is fine.

Later I have reinstalled ArcGIS10.0 and trying to run the same tool. The moment I start the process my ArcMap10.0 is getting closed. Interesting part is if I remove my toolbox related jar from /Desktop10.0/java/lib/ext folder it is working fine again.

Does anyone has any idea what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Have Encounter the problem a lot of times in arcmap add-in. The reason caused the problem was you code has error in logic.you have to handle the problem

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in an IDE?